# Simplest way to draw a tile-map in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my "game" I will draw a small map (i.e. 10x10 fields). Each field will represent a wall or ground. Depending on the answers to this question, the tiles will be either PNG images or simple color-filled rectangles.

What is your **best** recommended way to draw such a map in WPF? I want it to be **as simple as possible**, because the GUI part of this project is not very important, I just want it to be displayed in the center of the window.

Ideas that I have:

- `Canvas` + placing multiple `Rectangle`s as children
- Bitmap rendered by engine, displayed by GUI
- External library?

Comment: how do you define "best"? Ease of programming, performance, memory utlization, CPU...?

Comment: Ease of programming is most important

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPF is not so inclined toward *drawing* as Windows Forms is. WPF is more content-oriented.

The best way to 'draw' something is to generate the map out of existing WPF elements. For example, you could use a `Grid` or `UniformGrid`, or even a `Canvas` to lay out your content. You could programmatically add `Image`s and `Rectangle`s to the map, without worrying about any drawing code.

Here is an example:

```
UniformGrid grid = new UniformGrid();
grid.Columns = 10;
grid.Rows = 10;
grid.Width = columnWidth * 10;
grid.Height = rowHeight * 10;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        if (fields[x, y] is SomeImage)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = someImageSource;
            grid.Children.Add(img);
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Fill = someColor;
            grid.Children.Add(rect);
        }
    }
}
Canvas.SetLeft(grid, (canvas.Width - grid.Width) / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(grid, (canvas.Height - grid.Height) / 2);
canvas.Children.Add(grid);
```

You probably won't be able to use that as is, but you can fill in the missing pieces.

I recently did a project similar to this, using a `Canvas` to lay out `TextBlock`s, `Line`s and `Button`s. It is efficient and simple, a lot more than I expected.

Comment: See, comments such as this is exactly what I need. I dont have much experience in WPF, I code mostly in Java.. ;-)

Comment: A snippet showing how to draw 10x10 grid displayed in the very middle of a `Canvas` would be very nice to see ;-)

Comment: Do you think this would scale up? Say it was a 2000x2000 tile grid would this just give up and die? I'm currently facing this same situation and want to try and start on the right foot

Answer (score 0):

I would say use XAML if the UI is simple and you are looking for ease of programming, you can use the XMAL built-in designer in VS or Blend to draw the UI. Other options are to use DirectX or OpenGL which is much more powerful but have steep learning curve.

Comment: even if the map is not static, you can create the structure in XAML and bind the elements of the Map.

Comment: very nice idea! unfortunately, the size is not static. Imagine a map of a world in a game..

Comment: I thought you said it's 10x10? other options you have require using DirectX or OpenGL, which are 2D/3D drawing environments where you have to draw everything from scratch. You can generate XAML controls dynamically if you want.

Comment: @elmes; "i.e." = "id est" = "that is to say". If you meant "for example", use "e.g."